# Execute completion handler when condition is met

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

I have a function which relies on the completionHandler of another function. This completionHandler should be called when the delegate method `completedLogin` is called. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
class loginClass : LoginScreenDelegate {

    var loginCompleted : Bool = false

    func performLogin(completionHandler: (() -> Void)) {

        ...

        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            while self.loginCompleted != true {
                // Do nothing
            }
            completionHandler()
        })


    }

    func didLogin(sender: LogInScreen, success: Bool) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    func completedLogin(sender: LogInScreen) {
        self.loginCompleted = true
    }


}
```

However, using a while loop inside a background thread seems like a very resource intensive way. I have tried using `NSTimer()` but the problem is is that it executes another function so i cannot use my callback function anymore. Is there a better / resource friendly way to keep checking this?

Comment: you might want to store the `completionHandler` as an instance variable and call it explicitly from `completedLogin`.

Comment: I am afraid i do not know how that works, I tried googling the process but failed. Could you maybe provide a short explanation as to why/how that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a completion handler to the function which needs to be completed before the other like this:

```
func completedLogin(sender: LogInScreen, completionHandler :(evaluatedSuccessfully: Bool) -> ()){


self.loginCompleted = true
completionHandler(evaluatedSuccessfully: true)
}
```

And then you can just call this function in any other function like this:

```
completedLogin(sender: <your sender>){ success in

If success{
//do something
}

else{
//report an error
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class loginClass : LoginScreenDelegate {

    var loginCompleted : Bool = false
    var completionHandler: (() -> Void)!

    func performLogin(completionHandler: (() -> Void)) {

        ...

        self.completionHandler = completionHandler

    }

    func didLogin(sender: LogInScreen, success: Bool) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    func completedLogin(sender: LogInScreen) {
        self.loginCompleted = true
        self.completionHandler()
    }


}
```